# Sorting multilevel dict in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort the following dict by value of the 'sales_min' key:

```
mydict = {
    'NATION': {'sales_max': 1000, 'sales_min': 500, ...}, 
    'LOCAL':  {'sales_max': 250, 'sales_min': 0, ...},
    'REGION': {'sales_max': 500, 'sales_min': 250, ...}, 
    ...
}
```

I haven't found a good way to do it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need an ordered dictionary or do you just need to go through the sorted items and do something with them, eg. output

Comment: The Python Pandas library may be useful for you. This looks like a very good case for a DataFrame instead of a dict of dicts.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v):
       v['sales_min']))
OrderedDict([('LOCAL', {'sales_max': 250, 'sales_min': 0}), ('REGION', {'sales_max': 500, 'sales_min': 250}), ('NATION', {'sales_max': 1000, 'sales_min': 500})])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfect, however seems to be simpler the solution from @winston-ewert.

Comment: @tufla: Winston's answer gives you a list of tuples, whereas my answer gives you a mapping that you can index by key. It's not a matter of which is simpler, but rather which is appropriate given the situation.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you can't actually sort a dict, because a dict has no defined order. But you can convert it into a sorted list:

```
sorted(mydict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['sales_min'])
```

They lambda takes an elements from the `items()` list and returns the sales min value. By passing this function as they key parameter, python will sort it by that.